# JS. check if input attribute src contains text

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, src, attr

How Can i check if the below src contains the text "green"

```
 <input onclick="myfunction(\'' + 'match' + '\')" id="btn_match" type="image" src="http://localhost/content/tick_green.png" />
```

for example this is the closest i have got

```
if($('#btn_match [src*="green"]')==true ) console.log('success')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `indexOf` :

```
if( $('#btn_match').attr('src').indexOf('green') != -1 ) 
     console.log('success');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i had tried that indexof before but i must of coded incorrectly. Your example works

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to check the length of the jQuery selection, to see if any elements matched the selector

```
if ( $('#btn_match[src*="green"]').length > 0 ) 

   console.log('success')
```

Or just check the attribute

```
if ( $('#btn_match').attr('src').indexOf('green') !== -1 )

   console.log('success')
```